# Fragment methods: attach(), detach(), remove(), replace(), popBackStack()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, back-stack

I am very confused between these functions and their purposes. What I have observed that using `replace()` replaces the existing fragment with a new one. We can use `addToBackStack(null)` to put that fragment in back stack so we can go back to the previously shown fragment. Now when a fragment is added (or replaced) - `onAttach()` -> `onCreate()` etc.... methods of the fragment are called in order.

Now when we call `remove()` on the fragment from our activity, which functions of the fragment are called and in which order?

What does `attach()` and `detach()` do? Does `detach()` remove the fragment? And when these two `attach()` and `detach()` are used, which functions of the fragment are called and in which order??

Also, what happens on `popBackStack()`?? I mean which functions are called when we use `popBackStack()`on the fragment from our activity??

And when does onDestroy() called??

Thank you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> Now when we call remove() on the fragment from our activity, which functions of the fragment are called and in which order?

Look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html .

The order is: `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onDestroyView()`, `onDestroy()`, `onDetach()`

> What does attach() and detach() do? Does detach() remove the fragment? And when these two attach() and detach() are used, which functions of the fragment are called and in which order??

`attach()` and `detach()` is respectively associates or detaches the `Fragment` with/from the `Activity`. When attaching the `Fragment`, the `onAttach()` lifecycle method is called, when detaching, the `onDetach()` lifecycle method is called in the `Fragment`. For more information look at the link above.

> Also, what happens on popBackStack()?? I mean which functions are called when we use popBackStack()on the fragment from our activity??

If the `Fragment` hasn't been destroyed, then on `popBackStack()` the `onStart()` and `onResume()` methods are called. If the `Fragment` has been destroyed previously, then the lifecycle methods will be called starting from `onAttach()`. It's the same as, when you press the back button on `Activities`.

Comment: "on popBackStack() the onStart() and onResume() methods are called". How is this possible??? we are popping the fragment out, not adding it.

Comment: When you pop the backstack it means, that you remove your current fragment, and replace it with the previous one, where the previous fragment is stored in the backstack.

Comment: You pop the fragment from the backstack, not from the screen. It's the counterpart of `addToBackStack()`.

Comment: @vickey on popBackStack() the onStart() and onResume() methods are not called. I am looking a solution for it as I have to call a webservice. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava it depends on the transitions that pops, if hide/show was used, you won't get any onStart/onResume, however if last transaction was a replace - it would trigger as fragment is being built up from onAttach

Comment: @Tapirboy actually its been 2 years so I already figured out a way :D

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava if hide/show was used, then onHiddenChanged() is called when popBackStack() Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18375436/1911021

Comment: The answer about attach() and detach() is *incorrect*.
Calling `detach()` keeps the fragment attached to the activity so `onDetach()` is *not* called, but it detaches its view hierarchy so `onPause()`, `onStop()` and `onDestroyView()` are called, in order.
Calling `attach()` requires the fragment to be in the detached view state and will bring it back to normal state, calling in order: `onCreateView()`, `onActivityCreated()`, `onStart()` and `onResume()`.

Answer (score 13):

Just a note on `popBackStack()`.  It doesn't pop a fragment, it pops a fragment transaction.  So whatever the last fragment transaction was is reversed.  If you were displaying a `FragmentA` and your transaction was:

```
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.your_layout, fragmentB);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
```

It would replace `FragmentA` with `FragmentB`, and add that transaction (not the fragment) to the back stack.  If you then hit the back button, it pops the back stack and gets the transaction, which was "replace this `FragmentA` with a `FragmentB`". It then reverses that transaction.  Backwards, the instruction is to replace whatever the current fragment is with `FragmentA`.  If the original `FragmentA` still exists, it uses that one.  If it's been destroyed, it makes a new one.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose fragment A and fragment B was added to a container with the following steps:

```
1. Added fragment A =>  .replace(R.id.container, fragmentA) => addToBackStack(null)
2. Added fragment B =>  .replace(R.id.container, fragmentB) => addToBackStack(null)
3. Removed fragment B => fragmentManager.popBackStack();
```

Callbacks when fm.popBackStack() is called:

```
FragmentB: onPause()
FragmentB: onStop()
FragmentB: onDestroy()
FragmentB: onDetach()
FragmentA: onCreateView()
FragmentA: onViewCreated()
FragmentA: onActivityCreated()
FragmentA: onStart()
FragmentA: onResume()
```

Explanation: Why while removing and destroying fragment B using popBackStack(), fragment A view was created again and resumed?

Ans: When you added fragment B, you used replace() and addToBackStack(), so all the  fragments were removed from the container, and fragment B was added to the container. And, also this transaction was recorded in the Back stack.  So, when fm.popBackStack() is called, first the transaction is popped out from the back stack and so the operations reverted itself, therefore fragment b is removed from the container and destroyed. And all other fragments get added, for our case fragment A's view is added to the container. Also noted that fragment A's onAttach & onCreate() is not called because it has already been created & attached to the MainActivity earlier.

Back press on fragment B does the same thing:

```
If you press the back button, it calls fm.popBackStack() and pops the transaction.
```

Comment: But it doesn't destroy the fragment when you go back or replace I thought? I thought it is just paused in the background no?

Comment: No, it is destroyed when you press back button.