# Fragment lifecycle - which method is called upon show / hide?

Tags: android, android-fragments, lifecycle, fragmenttransaction

I am using the following method to switch between Fragments (in my NavigationDrawer) by showing / hiding them.

```
protected void showFragment(int container, Fragment fragment, String tag, String lastTag, boolean addToBackStack ) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        if ( lastTag != null && !lastTag.equals("")) {
            Fragment lastFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( lastTag );
            if ( lastFragment != null ) {
                transaction.hide( lastFragment );
            }
        }

        if ( fragment.isAdded() ) {
            transaction.show( fragment );
        }
        else {
            transaction.add( container, fragment, tag );
        }

        if ( addToBackStack ) {
            transaction.addToBackStack( tag );
        }

        transaction.commit();

        // set the active tag
        activeFragTag = tag;
    }
```

**What I am unclear about is which method of the Fragments lifecycle is called when I show or hide it?** (since there is no method such as onShow() or onHide() im not quite sure what to use). I want to perform specific actions upon showing and hiding a certain Fragment.

Comment: when you call **Fragment.show()** then at some point later, the fragment triggers `onCreate()`, followed by `onCreateDialog()`, followed by `onCreateView()`

Answer (score 132, accepted):

Similar to activity lifecycle, Android calls [onStart()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStart%28%29) when fragment becomes visible. `onStop()` is normally called when fragment becomes invisible, but it can also be called later in time.

Depending on your layout Android can call `onStart()` even, when your Fragment is not yet visible, but it belongs to a visible parent container. For instance, this is valid for `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` which requires you to override [`Fragment.setUserVisibleHint()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29) method. In any case, if you need to register/unregister BroadcastReceivers or other listeners, you can safely use `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods because those will be called always.

**Note:** Some fragment containers can keep invisible fragments started. To handle this situation you can override [`Fragment.onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged%28boolean%29). According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#isHidden%28%29), a fragment must be both *started and visible (not hidden)*, to be visible to the user.

**Update:** If you use `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` then a fragment below the drawer stays started and visible even when drawer is open. In this case you need to use `DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener()` and listen for `onDrawerClosed()` and `onDrawerOpened()` callbacks.

Comment: `onStop` and `onPause` are not called when a fragment becomes invisible using a transaction. Nevertheless `onHiddenChanged` is called as suggests s1rius answer

Comment: This doesn't work in NavigationDrawer. onHiddenChanged is not called on v4/v11 support lib.


onStart and onResume will be also called not every time, when drawer layout opens.

Comment: @drdrej The problem is that drawer does no hide fragment below completely. If you use DrawerLayout from support library, you need to use DrawerListener.

Comment: As stated, this answer is simply incorrect.

Answer (score 82):

I @Override this method and resolve my problem:

```
@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    super.onHiddenChanged(hidden);
    if (hidden) {
        //do when hidden
    } else {
       //do when show
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried to no resolve but using `setUserVisibleHint` as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/a/18375436/1815624 works

Comment: I want to frame this comment :) You are perfect

Answer (score 38):

**of course you can @Override the following method to do so:**

```
@Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser) {
            // Do your Work
        } else {
            // Do your Work
        }
    }
```

Comment: And one can easily know if the fragment is visible to user or not by calling `getUserVisibleHint()`

Comment: setUserVisibleHint works with view pager but not with regular fragment container.

Comment: Thanks this Solves My Problem :)

Comment: This worked for me on ViewPager. onHiddenChanged did not work.

Comment: Solved my problem!

Answer (score 5):

You can use 'onCreateView'(or 'onActivityCreated') and 'onHiddenChanged'.
Use 'onCreateView' for first show and use 'onHiddenChanged' for later.
'setMenuVisibility' is not called on transaction control.

```
@Override
public View OnCreateView() {
   // fragment will show first
}

@Override
public void onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden) {
    if (!hidden) {
        // fragment will show 
    }
    else {
        // fragment will hide
    }
}
```

Comment: onHiddenChanged() is not called with my fragment

Answer (score 3):

Fragment in view pager behaviour is different with regular fragment container.

Try this code:

```java
    boolean mIsVisibleToUser;

    /**
     * is visible to user
     */
    public void show() {
        //do when show
    }

    /**
     * is invisible to user
     */
    public void hide() {
        //do when gone
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!mIsVisibleToUser && getUserVisibleHint()) {
            mIsVisibleToUser = true;
            show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mIsVisibleToUser && getUserVisibleHint()) {
            mIsVisibleToUser = false;
            hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isResumed()) {
            if (mIsVisibleToUser != isVisibleToUser) {
                mIsVisibleToUser = isVisibleToUser;
                if (isVisibleToUser) show();
                else hide();
            }
        }
    }

    public boolean isVisibleToUser() {
        return mIsVisibleToUser;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)
{
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (visible && isResumed())
    {
         onResume();
    }
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();
    if (!getUserVisibleHint())
    {
        return;
    }

    //Add your code this section
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Only this worked for me!! and `setUserVisibleHint(...)` is now deprecated (I attached docs at end), which means some other answers are deprecated ;-)

```java
public class FragmentFirewall extends Fragment {
    /**
     * Required cause "setMenuVisibility(...)" is not guaranteed to be,
     * called after "onResume()" and/or "onCreateView(...)" method.
     */
    protected void didVisibilityChange() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (isResumed() && isMenuVisible()) {
            // Once resumed and menu is visible,
            // at last our Fragment is really visible to user.
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        didVisibilityChange();
    }

    @Override
    public void setMenuVisibility(boolean visible) {
        super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
        didVisibilityChange();
    }
}
```

Tested and works with `NaviagationDrawer` as well,
there `isMenuVisible()` will always return `true` (and `onResume()` seems enough, but we want to support `ViewPager` too).

> `setUserVisibleHint` is deprecated. If overriding this method, behavior implemented when passing in `true` should be moved to `Fragment.onResume()`, and behavior implemented when passing in `false` should be moved to `Fragment.onPause()`.

Answer (score 1):

Just try this in your **setUserVisibleHint()**

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser && getView() != null){
        isActive = true;
        init();
    }else if(isVisibleToUser && getView() == null){
        isActive = false;
    }else{
        isActive = true;
    }
}
```

And create this code in **onCreateView()** :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  if(!isActive){
      init();
  }
}
```

Comment: `isVisibleToUser && getView() != null` worked perfect for me!

Answer (score 1):

> Another way to calling fragment method when fragment is visible and you use viewpager in activity.

//first of all you create a interface

```
public interface ShowFragmentVisible{
      public void showFragment();}
```

//After that this interface implement inside Fragment like that

```
      public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements 
         ShowFragmentVisible {
            @Override
public void showFragment() {
}
```

// Now  goes your Activity then create object of interface and call inside when addOnViewpagerListener

```
   ShowFragmentVisible showFragmentVisible;

@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

    if (fragment instanceof ShowFragmentVisible) {
        showFragmentVisible = (ShowFragmentVisible) fragment;
    }

}
     //your viewpager method
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            if (position==0){
                showFragmentVisible.showFragment();

           }

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


this is another alternative,but its work for me successfully
```

Answer (score 0):

`setUserVisibleHint` call before `onCreateView`. and you can't update any View inside setUserVisibleHint I use

```
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible)
```

for **visibility and onHiddenChanged() didn't call for the first time**. it calls when the hidden state changes. because a `fragment is visible by default`. In order to achieve this method for the first time you have to call `mFragmentTransaction.hide(oldFragment)` then it will work

**Note**

if you want to use setUserVisible hint and update View [**Use this method**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24934483/3496570)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could override `setUserVisibleHint` or `setMenuVisibility` but if you need to access `Context` or `Activity`, they will be null in there!
There is another method `onStart` which always has the context available at hand, but it will only get called once upon creation of fragment and if you start moving between your fragments in a pager you will see that it won't get called in second view and afterwards.

So... what to do now?

The workaround is quite easy, use `onStart` for the first visit and `setMenuVisibility` for later ones.
Your code will probably look like below :

Fragment class:

```
public class MyFragmentClass{
    private boolean isCurrentVisible = false;
...

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (isCurrentVisible)
        doSth();
}

@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(boolean menuVisible){
    super.setMenuVisibility(menuVisible);
    this.isCurrentVisible = menuVisible;
    if(menuVisible && getContext() != null)
        doSth();
}
```

This way `Context` will always be available to `doSth()` method.