# Where should use PageViewer?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, navigation, android-viewpager

I have implemented **ViewPager** and number of **Fragment** as child, here every child override own `onAttach, onCreateView, onViewCreated and setUserVisibleHint`.

In my app navigation behaviour is random, it not be in sequence every time. Since page viewer **perform caching** to load extra child, and this is what my problem is. I am not sure exactly when I should initialise/release member of child class.

Required suggestion from you guys, will it be preferable to use PageViwer in this case or I should go with traditional activity flow for each of component.

Comment: Regarding random navigation, does it mean that the order of the items inside PagerAdapter will randomly change and already cached "next" item should be different? Or does it mean that the order is always the same but you want to jump between pages with more than 1 step? Can you describe example scenario step by step? That would be helpful to give yo a comprehensive answer.

Comment: For caching, if you use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter, it will manage the pages for you. As the documentation says, "This version of the pager is more useful when there are a large number of pages, working more like a list view. When pages are not visible to the user, their entire fragment may be destroyed, only keeping the saved state of that fragment." -  http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentStatePagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 2):

`ViewPager` is typically used for move efficient horizontal item to item navigation. Typical use cases would be

- Swiping through the related items (e.g. emails, images, songs of an album, etc.)
- Swiping between the tabs
- Swiping back-and-forth in a wizard-like activity

For more details you can read a section about [Swipe Views Android Design pattern](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/swipe-views.html).

Regarding the lifecycle, it basically uses the same lifecycle as any other Fragment. The only difference is, that lifecycle methods can be called a bit later or earlier than you expect, because of fragment's caching `ViewPager` implements.

> I am not sure exactly when I should initialise/release member of child class.

You should basically rely on two methods: `onStart()` and `onStop()`. In `onStart()` you create class members and initialize everything you want to. In `onStop()` method you should deinitialize everything and remove all listeners you set in `onStart()`.

Method `setUserVisibleHint()` is used independently of `onStart()` or `onStop()`. You **shoud better not** initialize or destroy anything in there. You must not consider it to the a lifecycle method, because it's not. It's there just to give you a hint, that your fragment is visible to the user. Here you can start or stop animation, or request data update or perform similar tasks. This is the only purpose of this method.

> Required suggestion from you guys, will it be preferable to use
>   PageViwer in this case or I should go with traditional activity flow
>   for each of component.

If your activity fits into one of the points mentioned about, I would suggest you to use `ViewPager`. Otherwise you might consider other options.

**Update:** Most likely you won't override `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` lifecycle methods of a fragment very often. You will use `onCreateView()` and `onDestroyView()` methods instead. There you can implement so called static initialization, the initialization which doesn't change while a fragment is still alive. This is layout initialization and similar tasks.

Comment: In general I agree with you but regarding use of onStart() and onStop()  i believe you are wrong. The best place for initializing members are onCreate() and onActivityCreated(), use second one for UI related members. For releasing use onDestroy() and onDestroyView(), again use second one for releasing UI related members. onStart() and onStop() are good for temporary disabling some functionality, not releasing completely.

Comment: @Loop The thing is, that if you use onCreate() and onDestroy() then your fragment will continue to receive updates and to consume resources even when activity is in background, but not yet destroyed. If you would use onStart() and onStop(), you would be using system resources more optimal. If you use Otto event bus, then this is what Square guys suggest too. I use start/stop in all my app with no issues at all. But, at the end, create/destroy is also a solution. Just memory and CPU consumption might be a bit higher.

Comment: Otto example is what I meant as disabling features. In other words depending services etc. That's the right spot. But @Shubh asked about members of the Fragment which initialization/releasing belongs to onCreate() and other methods mentioned by me.

Answer (score 1):

**ViewPager Usages**

Screen slides are transitions between one entire screen to another and are common with UIs like setup wizards or slideshows.

If you have good knowledge in Fragment than ViewPager is right component for implements.
Because viewpager provide a place which you can add fragment runtime.

For eg. 
   If you want to use TabBar in your project than viewpager is right component for using. Because it's provide a place which you can add Fragment runtime. Tabbar is common in android application. It's provide lot of functionality inbuild we can use to add fragment runtime.
Facebook app using ViewPager to manage tab. Viewpager provide smoothness of your application.

You can Download example from this url and check your requirement fulfill or not

[You can download the Example here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Hi, I totally agree what you mention here, but I have scenario mentioned in question. I should go with ViewPager or not in this case, mean how should manage overide method call.

Answer (score 1):

ViewPager

```
  It is an widget 

  Allows the user to swipe left or right to see an entirely new screen. 

  Easy  to show the user multiple tabs

  Dynamically add and remove pages (or tabs) at anytime.
```

To Read More: http://architects.dzone.com/articles/android-tutorial-using