# How to properly have camera preview in viewpager tab for Android?

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am using a viewpager with tab navigation for an Android project.  One of my tabs has a surfaceview with a camera preview.  The problem is that whenever I navigate to a neighboring tab, the preview in the camera tab starts even though the camera tab is not visible.  Not only does this slow my app down, but if I then navigate to another tab and then to the camera tab, my app attempts to restart the preview thus resulting in a crash.

I'm looking for advice on how to only start a camera preview if the fragment is visible(ie. tab is active).  And to finish preview as soon as tab is switched.

Thank you.

Comment: I solved it with the help of this answer:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161160/setuservisiblehint-called-before-oncreateview-in-fragment#comment45069545_24934483