# TTS is not reading the text of proper fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, text-to-speech

I guess I'll fail to explain the issue because it is WEIRD.

I need an app similar to online tutorials,the basic functionality is to switch among the pages(fragments in my case) and the content should read out.

So, I've followed [Mr.Tamada](http://www.androidhive.info/) " - The life saviour" tutorials [The TTS](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-text-to-speech-tutorial/) and [Fragments](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/) and I've merged them both.

Motto is to read the data in fragments.

Code:

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener
{
    private static TextToSpeech tts;
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);
        tv = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
        tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), TopRatedFragment.this);
        speakOut();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status)
    {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.US); 
            tts.setSpeechRate(0);  
            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "Language is not supported");
            } else { 
                speakOut();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    { 
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void speakOut()
    {
        tts.speak(tv.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
        Log.e("root ",  tv.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

The text in textview is reading out. But the text of 1st fragment is read in 2nd fragment that too only when I swipe backward.

fragment 3 --> fragment 2 (here fragment 1 text is read).

I really do not understand what is happening.

And when I open the app from recently opened apps list then it is reading its own text.

Kindly help if possible....Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the problem is that at start- `Fragment1` is loaded along with `Fragment2`. So u can hear contents from `Fragment1` and `Fragment2` resp.

Now when u navigate to `Fragment2` [already loaded so you cannot hear chapter2] then `Fragment3` is loaded so you can hear Chapter3.

When you navigate to `Fragment3`, then `Fragment1` is removed.

Now if you navigate from `Fragment3` to `Fragment2` then `Fragment1` is loaded. Hence u can hear chapter1.

Solution:- Simply check if the Fragment is visible and then perform the rest of action. In your case TTS thing.

1. Extend `FragmentPagerAdapter`.
2. override `setUserVisibleHint()`.

   ```
   @Override
   public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser)
   {
       super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
       Log.d(TAG, "setUserVisibleHint: " + isVisibleToUser);
   }
   ```

Now u can perform ur action inside `setUserVisibleHint() if(isVisibleToUser){}` instead of `onCreateView()` okay.

Comment: How do I initialize the views? Now am doing it inside `onCreateView()` but it is executing `setUserVisibleHint` first, I've tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24934483/4361127) but Stil am getting NPE