# Can I call setUserVisibleHint manually?

Tags: android, fragment

I switch two fragments following some actions, but setUserVisibleHint can't be called, so I want to call it manually. Is that right?

Comment: Can you be more explicit and yes you can override `setUserVisibleHint()` method

Comment: How did u achieve this finally ?  @BajiraoShinde : could you pls elaborate more on this .

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161160/setuservisiblehint-called-before-oncreateview-in-fragment @AndroidGuy