# Android change title when using back button

Tags: android, back

My activity:

```
TextView title;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Overview overview = new Overview();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.mycontainer, overview)
                .commit();
    }
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    //Some more code

    title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.screentitle);
    title.setText("Overzicht");


}



@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.nav_menu_overview:
            title.setText("Overzicht");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new Overview()).addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

            break;
        case R.id.nav_menu_favourites:
            title.setText("Favorieten");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new Favourites()).addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();

            break;

        case R.id.nav_menu_profile:
            title.setText("Profiel");
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mycontainer, new Profile()).addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
            break;
    }
```

So, right now, the title gets changed if I use my menu to change fragments. However, if I use the android backbutton, the title doesn't get changed back. How can I change the title back whenever the back button is used?

Comment: Do you only have one activity and 3 fragments?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24161160/setuservisiblehint-called-before-oncreateview-in-fragment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply override the `onBackPressed` method of the activity and handle the scenario.

A much better approach would be you could set the title inside the fragment `onViewCreated` so that way whichever fragment is on top will automatically set the tile you want to set.

eg: Setting the title inside the fragment

```
Toolbar toolbar= (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
toolbar.setTitle("What ever you want to set");
```

Also don't set the title in `onNavigationItemSelected` its should be used to navigate not to set the title.

Answer (score 0):

Put the activity title changing code in `onResume()` of the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    //Some more code 

    title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.screentitle);
    title.setText("Overzicht");

}
```