# How to fix not found view in fragment in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

In my application I want get some data from server and show it into `RecyclerView` and for this I should use `Fragment`.

I want when users see `fragment` call my API call method. but when use below code, show me Force close error.

**Code:**

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser){
        getData(getActivity());
    }
}
```

**Error :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ProgressBar.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.app.test.Fragments.MainNotificationFrags.NotificationAllFrag.getData(NotificationAllFrag.java:157)
    at com.app.test.Fragments.MainNotificationFrags.NotificationAllFrag.setUserVisibleHint(NotificationAllFrag.java:142)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:157)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1266)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1116)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1642)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1658)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1081)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1438)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:724)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:615)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5466)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2636)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17496)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2031)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1193)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1400)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1078)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5875)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5349)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

**Fragment full code:**

```
public class NotificationAllFrag extends Fragment {

    @BindView(R.id.mainNotification_recyclerView)
    RecyclerView mainNotification_recyclerView;
    @BindView(R.id.mainNotification_noNotificationTxt)
    TextView mainNotification_noNotificationTxt;
    @BindView(R.id.mainNotification_progressBar)
    ProgressBar mainNotification_progressBar;
    @BindView(R.id.newsPageLoadLay)
    RelativeLayout newsPageLoadLay;
    private Context context;
    private List<Datum> model = new ArrayList<>();
    public static NotificationListAdapter notificationListAdapter;
    private SharedPrefrencesHandler prefrencesHandler;
    private String token = "";
    private LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    public NotificationAllFrag() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_all, container, false);

        //Initialize
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        context = getActivity();
        notificationListAdapter = new NotificationListAdapter(context, model);
        prefrencesHandler = new SharedPrefrencesHandler(context);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        //RecyclerView
        mainNotification_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mainNotification_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        //Get token
        token = prefrencesHandler.getFromShared(SharedPrefrencesKeys.TOKEN.name());
        // Lazy loader
        newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mainNotification_recyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerLinearPage1(layoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                ExploreSendData sendData = new ExploreSendData();
                sendData.setPageIndex(current_page);
                sendData.setPageSize(10);
                sendData.setShowFollows(true);
                sendData.setShowMovies(false);
                sendData.setShowNews(false);
                sendData.setShowReplies(true);
                sendData.setShowSeries(false);
                sendData.setShowSuggestions(true);

                newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
                Call<ExploreResponse> call = api.getExplore(token, sendData);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<ExploreResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ExploreResponse> call, Response<ExploreResponse> response) {
                        if (response.body().getData() != null && response.body().getStatusCode() != 401
                                && response.body().getStatusCode() != 402) {
                            if (response.body().getData().size() > 0) {
                                notificationListAdapter.addNewItem(response.body().getData());
                                //Gone no explore
                                newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                        } else {
                            prefrencesHandler.remove(SharedPrefrencesKeys.TOKEN.name());
                            startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
                        }

                        newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ExploreResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                        newsPageLoadLay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        getData(getActivity());

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser){
            getData(getActivity());
        }
    }

    public void getData(final Context context) {
        ExploreSendData sendData = new ExploreSendData();
        sendData.setPageIndex(1);
        sendData.setPageSize(10);
        sendData.setShowFollows(true);
        sendData.setShowMovies(false);
        sendData.setShowNews(false);
        sendData.setShowReplies(true);
        sendData.setShowSeries(false);
        sendData.setShowSuggestions(true);

        mainNotification_progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        InterfaceApi api = ApiClient.getClient().create(InterfaceApi.class);
        Call<ExploreResponse> call = api.getExplore(
                new SharedPrefrencesHandler(context).getFromShared(SharedPrefrencesKeys.TOKEN.name()), sendData);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ExploreResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ExploreResponse> call, Response<ExploreResponse> response) {
                if (response.body().getData() != null && response.body().getStatusCode() != 401
                        && response.body().getStatusCode() != 402) {
                    if (response.body().getData().size() > 0) {
                        model.clear();
                        model.addAll(response.body().getData());
                        notificationListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        mainNotification_recyclerView.setAdapter(notificationListAdapter);
                        //Gone no explore
                        mainNotification_noNotificationTxt.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        mainNotification_noNotificationTxt.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mainNotification_recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                } else {
                    prefrencesHandler.remove(SharedPrefrencesKeys.TOKEN.name());
                    startActivity(new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class));
                }

                mainNotification_progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ExploreResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                mainNotification_progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
```

How can I fix it? Please help

Comment: I guess the visibility method is called before the actual view of the fragment is made which leaves you with the exception. Try a different approach on when the fragment is visible or not.

Comment: you can write logic inside setUserVisibleHint() method because that method call before  onCreateView. otherwise you can set handler and delay getData() method for some time

Comment: i would suggest you to call the getData method in onCreateView itself after all the views are initialized

Comment: else if you are switching fragments then what you can do is create an interface implement it on the fragment and call the interface method whenever you are switching the fragment from your activity

Comment: @MaheshVayak, I write Handler code and set 5s , but after 5s again show me error

Comment: `setUserVisibleHint` is used for when the fragment are visible to user or not , for example when you are switching the multiple fragments in the view pager and u need to load the data in the `onCreateView` or `onViewCreated`

Comment: U can check your adapter , getItemCount and everyThing

Comment: @KoVartthan, can you send to me your skype ID my bro?

Comment: I cant use skype right now @Gone , u can ask your doubts here , post your code fully for clear reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is not proper solution but it 100% working

```
 @Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
     super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
     if (isVisibleToUser && mainNotification_recyclerView!=null){
         getData(getActivity());
     }
 }



 @Override
 public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
     if (getUserVisibleHint()) {
         getData(getActivity());
     }
 }
```

> it was work with multiple or single tab when user was go on tab that time initialize data
>
> it can help to load data faster even load in all fragment at same time

Comment: not work me :(  :(

Comment: can you send to me your skype id? please

Answer (score 1):

it seems that `setUserVisibleHint()` called before `onCreateView()`

watch this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24934483/4299356)

Comment: this is better as comment, not as answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**We should know that `setUserVisibleHint` is loaded before `onCreateView` .**

```
private boolean isVisible = false;
private View view;

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        isVisible = true;
        onVisible();
    }
}

// onVisible method
private void onVisible() {
    // edited here 
    if (isVisible && view != null && mainNotification_progressBar != null) {
        getData(getActivity());
    }
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notification_all, container, false);
    // add ButterKnife here
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    onVisible();
    return view;
}
```

Comment: not work me :(  :(

Comment: sorry .........

Comment: I also want to know the error about it.

Comment: You can try it again .@Gone

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 @Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser){
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                getData(getActivity());
            }
        },3000);

    }
}
```

Hope this help you...if you need any help you can ask

Comment: I write Handler code and set 5s , but after 5s again show me error

Comment: please add more time to delay call getData method

Comment: I added 10s, but again show error

Comment: please first comment progress bar visibility code and check it

Comment: please remove getData() mehtod inside onCreateview