# onCreateView of second fragment (tab) is called while on the first

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs, fragmentpageradapter

I have 10 tabs in my `activity`. As soon as I open the activity the first fragment gets displayed but the method (AsyncTask) present in the next fragment gets called. And **if I go to the next tab say 3rd tab then the method present in the 4th `fragment` gets called and so on.**

I don't understand this behavior. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

You must know how the `viewPager` works populating the `fragment` in the different positions

When you start on the position 0, then the `fragment` on the position 0 and the one of the position 1 are created.

Then when you swipe to the position 1 the `fragment` on the 2 position is created, so you have now the three `fragments` created on the different positions (0,1,2..assuming you have only 3 pages on the `viewPager`).

We swipe to the position 2, the last one, and the `fragment` on the first position (0) get destroy, so we have now the `fragments` on the positions 2 and 3.

This is how `Fragment` LifeCycle Works

you can set `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); // 2 is just an example` to limit it

If you want some code to execute when `Fragment` become Visible to User add part of code in `setUserVisibleHint` method

Answer (score 3):

By default it is `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1)` , meaning View pager will by default load atleast 1 on the right and one on the left tab of current tab.

It is done so, mostly because there is a point when you slide viewpager, when certain area of both tabs is visible. For those smooth transitions preloading is required.

You **cannot** set it `viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0).`

The only way out is to use this method `setUserVisibleHint`
add this to your fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // load data here
    }else{
       // fragment is no longer visible
    }
}
```

This will be called only when that particular tab is visible to user, so only  then you can call all loading function.

check [sample example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24934483/2826147)

Comment: Yes this helped. But if the data was fetched and loaded then while coming back to the previous tab  why do I have to fetch and load it again?

Comment: because that will not be stored any where. so you need to load it again.

Comment: ontabselection it will reload that fragment and in that fragment you methods wil be called according to its lifecycle so it is will load data again @VaibhavDhunde

Comment: I am still working on the same. Will surely credit you. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2):

Put your AsyncTask method inside this.

You can override setMenuVisibility like this:

```
@Override
public void setMenuVisibility(final boolean visible) {
   if (visible) {
      //execute AsyncTask method
   }

   super.setMenuVisibility(visible);
}
```

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 1):

```
Override below method and move your code for Aync task into this instead of onStart() or onCreateView.

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // Load your data here or do network operations here
        isFragmentLoaded = true;
    }
}
```